# A hook that runs only when the theme is previewed

Tags: themes

Is there a function or a hook that runs only when a theme is previewed?

I'm referring to the preview feature that you get on the Appearance->Themes page.

The reason for this is that I want to **change specific design aspects on the theme but only when the user is previewing it**.

Comment: Have you searched a [database](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks)?

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use the ?preview=true in the url something like :

```
if ($GET['preview']) {
// your hook or function
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When I ask myself questions like this, I usually find that the UNIX `find` command, combined with [Adam Brown's Wordpress Hooks](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook) site gives me some pointers.

When sitting in a WordPress root, running `find . -name '*.php' | xargs grep -i preview | grep -i action` shows that there's 3 hooks that might be useful, although you'd need to experiment a bit. There's `start_previewing_theme` and `stop_previewing_theme` hooked from the`WP_Customize_Manager` class in `/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-manager.php` and `setup_theme` hooked from `/wp-includes/theme.php`.

Cross-checking Adam's WordPress Hooks site also shows up these hooks; http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/start_previewing_theme, http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/stop_previewing_theme and http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/setup_theme.

The `setup_theme` hooks is also interesting as the hook handler in `theme.php` is `preview_theme`; hopefully one or a combination of these hooks will give you what you want.